# NFS Hot Pursuit 2010 Offline Photo Mode?

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

How do I use photo mode offline in NFS Hot Pursuit 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method **simulates photo mode** while offline

- Download NFS Hot [Pursuit Camera Hack](http://www.tocaedit.com/IB/index.php?app=downloads&showfile=74).
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on at the moment you like to take picture.
- Press <kbd>Num 7</kbd> to hide pause menu
- Use <kbd>Num +</kbd> and <kbd>Num -</kbd> to move camera in any direction
- Press <kbd>right shift</kbd> to speed up camera
- Then use FRAPS or any other software to take screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

Since the TocaEdit link doesn't work, go to Racer_S's alternative section.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4lfqq0DpUo-UG5ZX2NZZ21xTEE&usp=sharing&tid=0B4lfqq0DpUo-WGV0OVVTS1Z0LVk#list